# Enlightening explanation of a theorem of Zimmert's

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry, lattices-in-lie-groups

I'd like to know wether anyone has ever read an enlightening explanation (e.g. with geometric argument) of the following paper:

Zimmert, R.
[Zur $SL_2$ der ganzen Zahlen eines imaginär-quadratischen Zahlkörpers](http://dx.doi.org/doi:10.1007/BF01418852). (German)
Invent. Math. 19 (1973), 73–81.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps if you add a link to a copy of the paper...

Comment: One can see Invent. online; for example, this paper is at http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN356556735_0019&DMDID=DMDLOG_0012